# Why responsive images with img srcset and sizes will always load the largest source?

Tags: html, image, srcset

I'm learning the usage of HTML img srcset on MDN and there are few questions confusing me.

**Questions:**

1. Regarding to example, why the browser load elva-fairy-480w.jpg when the viewport width is under 600px?
2. Can img srcset work like media query for switching the image source if vp width has changed?

**Example:**

https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/responsive-images/responsive.html

**MDN reference:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

I inspected the network tab and it was loading the elva-fairy-800w.jpg every time even if my vp width was less than 600px.

** I tried to use incognito window or hard refresh and the results are the same.

From my understanding, I expect the browser will load the 480w image when viewport width is less than 600px as defined in sizes attribute. And load the 800w image when its greater than 600px.

```
<img
  srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w, elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
  sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
         800px"
  src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg"
  alt="Elva dressed as a fairy" />
```